# AutoScaling in Docker Containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dcos

I have been looking into Docker containerization for a while now but few things are still confusing to me. I understand that all the containers are grouped into a cluster and cluster management tools like Docker Swarm, DC/OS, Kubernetes or Rancher can be used to manage docker containers. I have been testing out Container cluster management with DC/OS and Kubernetes, but still a few questions remain unanswered to me.

**How does auto scaling in container level help us in production servers?** How does the application serve traffic from multiple containers?

Suppose we have deployed a web application using containers and they have auto scaled. How does the traffic flow to the containers? How are the sessions managed?

What metrics are calculated for autoscaling containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoscaling in DC/OS (note: Mesosphere is the company, DC/OS the open source project) the autoscaling is described in detail in the [docs](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/tutorials/autoscaling/). Essentially the same as with Kubernetes, you can use either low-level metrics such as CPU utilization to decide when to increase the number of instances of an app or higher-level stuff like app throughput, for example using the [Microscaling](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/tutorials/autoscaling/microscaling-queue/) approach.

Regarding your question how the routing works (how are requests forwarded to an instance, that is a single container running): you need a load balancer and again, DC/OS provides you with this out of the box. And again, the options are detailed out in the [docs](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/service-discovery/load-balancing-vips/), essentially: HAProxy-based North-South or IPtables-based, East-West (cluster internal) load balancers.

Comment: In the case of DC/OS, the most common inbound LB is Marathon-LB, which has an autoscaling example: https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb & https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb-autoscale

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes has concept called `service`. A Kubernetes Service is an abstraction which defines a logical set of Pods and a policy by which to access them. Kubernetes uses services to serve traffic from multiple containers. You can read more about services [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies).

AFAIK, Sessions are managed outside kubernetes, but Client-IP based session affinity can be selected by setting service.spec.sessionAffinity to "ClientIP". You can read more about Service and session affinity [here](http://nishadikirielle.blogspot.in/2016/03/load-balancing-kubernetes-services-and.html)

Multiple metrics like cpu and memory can be used for autoscaling containers. There is a good [blog](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/07/autoscaling-in-kubernetes.html) you can read about autoscaling, when and how.

Comment: Useful info from the blogs provided. I have full knowlege upon how to set up kubernetes cluster and all...my question is on how multiple containers serve the request coming from multiple users using a single service? how does it balance the load and how does service recognize which session is sticked with which container?what its use coming to live production applications.

Comment: There are images in the same section - http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies - did you see that, the service can behave like a load balancer.

Comment: Yeah that explains a part...but how are those services maintained? Route configurations and all...any idea with respect to Mesosphere?

Comment: this is not a simple question. As far as it goes for typical services, the current implementation is based on iptables. Normally there is a random probability matching in place, but if you add `sessionAffinity:ClientIP` there will be new rules added using `recent` module to maintain same backend match. For ingesting traffic you might use Ingress and IngressController like contrib-nginx-ingress which does not go via iptables but adds endpoints directly to backend list therefore handling things like session affinity in its own way